# How to refresh page from left menu

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin forms Using MVVM..Used burger example to have left hand side menu.

```
    //MainPage
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
        {
            int idOfNewPage;
            Dictionary<int, NavigationPage> MenuPages = new Dictionary<int, NavigationPage>();
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
    
                MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Products, (NavigationPage)Detail);
            }
    
            public async Task NavigateFromMenu(int id)
            {
                if (!MenuPages.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    switch (id)
                    {
                        case (int)MenuItemType.Products:
                            MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ProductPage()));
                            break;
                        case (int)MenuItemType.Shopping:
                            MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ShoppingPage()));
                            break;
                        case (int)MenuItemType.Browse:
                            MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ItemsPage()));
                            break;
                        case (int)MenuItemType.About:
                            MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new AboutPage()));
                            break;
                    }
    
                    idOfNewPage = id;
                }
    
                idOfNewPage = id;
    
                var newPage = MenuPages[id];
    
                if (newPage != null)
                {
                    Detail = newPage;
    
                    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                        await Task.Delay(100);
    
                    IsPresented = false;
                }
            }
    }
    
     [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
        {
            MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
            List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
        
            public MenuPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
                {
                    new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Products, Title="Products", Icon =  "back_nav.png", Name = "test" },
                    new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.ShoppingCart, Title="Shopping Cart", Icon =  "back_nav.png"},
                    new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Browse, Title="Browse", Icon =  "back_nav.png"},
                    new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.About, Title="About", Icon =  "back_nav.png"}
                };
    
                ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;
       
                ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                     return;
    
                    var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;
                    var MenuBtnClicked = (string)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Title;
    
    
                    await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
    
                    ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = null;
                };
            }
}
```

So this all works fine, I can use the menu on the left to jump back and fourth from pages.
However the issue lies on the shoppingPage.

A list view of products is displayed on the products page.(below) If the user changes the quantity of product WineQuantityChanged() is called. Updating the quantity on screen
and calling - UpdateShoppingCartItems(). which adds the product into the DrinksToPurchaseList.
Now, when the user clicks the shopping cart icon (added as a toolbaritem, not from menu) the code calls ShoppingClicked() which populates App.globalShoppingCartOC with the DrinksToPurchase list
and loads the shopping cart page.

```
        //ProductPage.cs
     public ProductPage()
            {
            
              PopulateQuantityPicker();
    
                InitializeComponent();
                
                  productPage_ViewModal = new ProductPageViewModel();
                  
                   NoItemsInShoppingCart.Text = App.NoOfItemsInShoppingCartGlobalVar;
                   
                     BindingContext = productPage_ViewModal;
                     
                     }
                     
            
            
            
            private async void ShoppingClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 //global list storing up to date products and quantites
                App.globalShoppingCartOC = DrinksToPurchase;
                await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(1);
            }
            
  void WineQuantityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = (Picker)sender;
            int newQuantity = picker.SelectedIndex;
            string winePickerId = picker.Id.ToString();
            int oldQuantity = -1;
            int tempDiffOfValues = 0;
            var product = (ProductModel)picker.BindingContext;
//code to update quantity 

//update shopping cart items
                UpdateShoppingCartItems(product, newQuantity);
                NoItemsInShoppingCart.Text = quantityOfProducts.ToString();
                App.NoOfItemsInShoppingCartGlobalVar = quantityOfProducts.ToString();

           }
        }


        //update item in shopping cart with new quantity
        void UpdateShoppingCartItems(ProductModel product, int quantity)
        {

            if (!DrinksToPurchaseList.Contains(product))
            {
                product.Quantity = quantity;
                DrinksToPurchaseList.Add(product);
            }
            else
            {
                ProductModel result = DrinksToPurchaseList.Where(x => x.ProductId == product.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    //remove from list
                    if (quantity < 1)
                    {
                        DrinksToPurchaseList.Remove(result);
                    }
                    else // else update new quantity
                    {
                        result.Quantity = quantity;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            
            
            //ProductPage.xaml
            
             <ToolbarItem x:Name="NumberOfItemsInShoppingCart" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingClicked"/>
            
             <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
                <Button Text="Wine" Clicked="WineClicked" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding WineList}" x:Name="WineListView" IsVisible="False" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" HeightRequest="1500">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                               
                                <Grid x:Name="Wine" RowSpacing="25">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ProductId}" VerticalOptions="End" IsVisible="False"/>
                                    <controls:CircleImage  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="66" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ProductName}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}"/>
                                    <Picker Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" SelectedIndexChanged="WineQuantityChanged" SelectedIndex="{Binding Quantity}">
                                        <Picker.Items>
                                            <x:String>0</x:String>
                                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                                            <x:String>2</x:String>
                                            <x:String>3</x:String>
                                            <x:String>4</x:String>
                                            <x:String>5</x:String>
                                            <x:String>6</x:String>
                                        </Picker.Items>
                                    </Picker>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

From the shopping cart page the user can also change the quantity of an item,calling QuantityChanged()-> calling  UpdateShoppingCartItems() and re-populating App.globalShoppingCartOC with ShoppingCartViewModel.ShoppingCartList(which holds the new quantity)
say for example they change the quantity and then return to the products page (from the left menu) .

(which should call OnAppearing() on ProductPage) and reload the VM?

```
    public ShoppingCartPage ()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                if (App.globalShoppingCartOC != null)
                {
                    foreach (ProductModel Model in App.globalShoppingCartOC)
                    {
                        if (Model.Quantity > 0)
                        {
//populate LV with global shopping OC
                            Model.SubTotalForItem = Model.Quantity * Model.Price;
                            ShoppingCartViewModel.ShoppingCartList.Add(Model);//ShoppingCartList is the ListView on xaml
                            TotalForAllItems += Model.SubTotalForItem;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                this.BindingContext = this;
                BindingContext = ShoppingCartViewModel;
            }
    
         void QuantityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    //updates correct quantity on screen and calls
    //UpdateShoppingCartItems()
    }
    
        //update item in shopping cart with new quantity
            void UpdateShoppingCartItems(ProductModel product, int quantity)
            {
                ProductModel result = ShoppingCartViewModel.ShoppingCartList.ToList().Find(x => x.ProductId == product.ProductId);
    
                if (result != null)
                {
                    //remove from list
                    if (quantity < 1)
                    {
                        ShoppingCartViewModel.ShoppingCartList.Remove(result);
                    }
                    else // else update new quantity
                    {
                        result.Quantity = quantity;
                    }
                }
    
                App.globalShoppingCartOC = ShoppingCartViewModel.ShoppingCartList;
            }
    
        //xaml
          <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
    
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingCartList}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                    <ListView.Header>
                        <Button Text="Place Order" Clicked="OrderPlaced_BtnClicked"/>
                    </ListView.Header>
                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <Label x:Name="TotalForItems" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="20,20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </ListView.Footer>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
    
                                <Grid x:Name="ShoppingCartGrid" RowSpacing="25" ColumnSpacing="10">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" VerticalOptions="End" IsVisible="False"/>
                                    <controls:CircleImage  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="66" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ProductName}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}"/>
    
                                    <Picker Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" SelectedIndexChanged="QuantityChanged" SelectedIndex="{Binding Quantity}">
                                        <Picker.Items>
                                            <x:String>0</x:String>
                                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                                            <x:String>2</x:String>
                                            <x:String>3</x:String>
                                            <x:String>4</x:String>
                                            <x:String>5</x:String>
                                            <x:String>6</x:String>
                                        </Picker.Items>
                                    </Picker>
    
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
```

Now, from here I need to reload all the products from 'WineList' from productPage_ViewModal.WineList and iterate though the App.globalShoppingCartOC, updating any new quantites.

The problem is I can step through and OnAppearing does this, but when the page reloads, it shows the original quantities, from when the user first moves from the productpage, to the shopping cart page. (so the quantites stored in the drinksToOrder )

**AMEND**

updated code to include OnAppearing in the ProductPage

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        
        if (App.globalShoppingCartOC != null)
        {
            if (App.globalShoppingCartOC.Count > 0)
            {
                 foreach(var item in App.globalShoppingCartOC)
                {
                    if(item.Genre == "Wine")
                    {
                        productPage_ViewModal.WineList.Where(x => x.ProductId == item.ProductId).FirstOrDefault().Quantity = item.Quantity;
                    }
                }

                 WineListView.ItemsSource = productPage_ViewModal.WineList;
                 
                  this.BindingContext = this.productPage_ViewModal;
                  
                            }
        }
    }
```

So stepping through this I can see the I have updated the correct quantity of the item in  productPage_ViewModal.WineList and in WineListView.ItemsSource

then even tired to bindingContext again...but the page still loads the original DrinksToPurchaseList after returning from the shopping cart page

Why is this? why cant I refresh the VW to update?

Comment: if the actual problem is on the ProductsPage, showing the code for that page would be helpful.  Generally, I'd suggest using OnAppearing to refresh the data every time the page is visited.  Alternately, you could use a common VM between the pages

Comment: Jason thanks for reply. I have included code for ProductsPage, and now I have added in OnAppearing, which is called when returned to products page, from shopping cart. I can see VM and itemSource of Listview are updated but it still shows old obseravableCollection - DrinksToOrder on screen....please see update of Q to include this thanks...any advice?

Comment: "still shows old obseravableCollection" and "still loads the original DrinksToPurchaseList" - based on the code you posted I can't tell what either of those are.

Comment: Sorry - I have posted ShoppingCart code now as well... and added better explaining

Comment: that really doesn't answer either of my questions.  If you're able to post your solution somewhere I can take a quick look at it

Comment: your data is updating to the new Quantity, but the Picker in your XAML does not use data binding so there is nothing to tell it that it should display the correct quantity

Comment: im sorry I must have removed that and not realised before my last commit, if you look at my code in the OP I have SelectedIndex="{Binding Quantity}"> for the picker on the ProcutPage, but it still isnt showing the correct quantity?

Comment: Have tried changing the name of a product when returning from shopping cart to product page, and I can see it works in the code, inside OnAppearing, but again, does not update on screen...can you see what I am missing? thank you

Comment: @John Do you have any BindingContext like `BindingContext = productPage_ViewModal;` except the `OnAppearing`?

Comment: yes I also have it at the bottom of the constructor on the ProductPage()....I can see by stepping through the code that the VM is updating and it is assigning the correct values to the bindingContext, the screen is just not refreshing??

Comment: @John I guess so. You could use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to updates.

Comment: Yes will look at this thanks for reply @WendyZang-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

```
Create an event on master page, invoke event from master page in your case blog and consume that event on another page where you want to refresh data..
on master page what you've to do is..
declare event..
public delegate void refreshDelegate();
public static event  refreshDelegate refreshEvent;
__
now invoke this event,
  refreshEvent?.inovke();

now,
   on the page where you want to refresh data, at constructor access the declared event,
masterpage.refreshEvent+=masterpage_refreshEvent;  
   private void masterpage_refreshEvent()
  { 
BindData();
}
       
now, bind the data in invoked event, it'll refresh your screen as expected.
```